# how is my 32bits ubuntu using 16g ram

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I recently found my qa server is running a 32-bits Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system by mistake cause what I wanted is a 64-bits copy,but what`s odd is that the system is using my 16g ram memory as normal,

so is there anyone has an idea how this works? i dont think i used PAE ,so 32-bits system can only use 4g ram,right?

here is my system info:

```
uname -a:
Linux qa-server 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 
i686 GNU/Linux

free -h:
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G       5.9G       9.8G       348M        81M       1.6G
-/+ buffers/cache:       4.2G        11G
Swap:          15G       2.6M        15G
```

Comment: As of Ubuntu 12.10, the 32-bit x86 version uses PAE by default. So indeed you're using PAE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using PAE, otherwise I don't think it's possible. Each process on your system is still limited to 4GB of ram each, because that is your virtual adress space on 32-bit. The memory management unit can ensure that in total there will be more memory used than 4GB.